# Time complexity/performance of insertion operation for a Queue implementation (In java)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, queue, time-complexity, implementation

What is the performance of the insertion operation for a Queue implemented as:

(a) an array, with the items in unsorted order

(b) an array, with the items in sorted order

(c) a linked list, with the items in unsorted order.

For each operation, and each implementation, give the performance in Big Oh notation and explain enough of the algorithm to justify your answer. (e.g. it takes O(n) times because in the worse case.... the algorithm does such and such....).

Please explain in detail, it'll help me out a lot!

Comment: Hmm? I don't understand, what to do with unsorted and sorted order?

Comment: I say ArrayQueue is generally the name given to the class for the queue implementation  of an Array and similarly linkedQueue for a linked list.

Comment: http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/docs/edu/colorado/collections/ArrayQueue.html
For ArrayQueue "add(E item)" is the insertion operation. 
Yeah I'm also confused though why unsorted and sorted is significant here. The question seems confusing to me.
Maybe this is related to priorityQueue? Should I read more about these?

Comment: http://www.w3professors.com/Data/Courses/Data-Structure/Algorithms/Queue/Insert-Into-Queue.pdf

Here's something I found online, I don't know if this means anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: it depends on your data structure.

In a naive array-based implementation (Assuming fixed size), I think it's pretty obvious that insertion is a constant operation (That is, O(1)), assuming that you don't run off the end of the array. This is similar in a cyclic array, with similar assumptions.

A dynamic array is a little more complicated. A dynamic array is a fixed-size array that you enlarge once it's filled to a certain point. So for a dynamic array that resizes when it reaches length *k*, the first *k-1* insertions are constant (Just like inserting into an ordinary array) and the *k*-th insertion takes O(*k*+1) - the cost of duplicating the contents of the array into a larger container, and then inserting the element. You can show that this works out to O(1) insertion time, but that may be out of scope for your course.

As others have noted, sorted order doesn't affect a standard queue. If you are in fact dealing with a priority queue, then there are lots of possible implementations, which I'll let you research on your own. The best insertion time is O(1), but that implementation has some disadvantages. The standard implementation is O(log *n*) insertion.

With linked lists, the insertion time will depend on whether the head of the list is the head of the queue (i.e., whether you add onto the head or the tail).

If you're adding onto the head, then it's pretty easy to see that insertion is O(1). If you're adding onto the tail, then it's also easy to see that insertion is O(*n*) for a list of length *n*. The main point is that, whichever implementation you choose, insert will always be one of O(1) or O(*n*), and removal will always be the other.

However, there is a simple trick that will let you get both insert and removal to O(1) in either case. I'll leave it to you to consider how to do that.

Comment: Is O(k+1) any different than O(k)?
For linked lists I believe I heard that the elements were being inserted from the front of the line and removed from the end of the line. At-least in this class.
This would make remove O(n) and add O(1) for linked lists.

Comment: O(k) and O(k+1) are equivalent, but you would typically write O(k). I chose to be more precise because I wanted to emphasize exactly what was happening under the hood. As for your linked lists, if I'm understanding correctly then what you call "front" I called "head", and what you called "back" I called "tail". As I said, though, there's a way to get insertion to O(1) regardless of that implementation detail

Comment: I'm guessing getting around that uses a double linked list?

Comment: You're on the right track, but a doubly-linked list won't give you that optimization. Recall that the nodes in a doubly-linked list reference their parents as well as their children; although that's useful is some contexts, it doesn't address what my algo prof used to call "the essential fact" of the insertion algorithm.